# having count in multiple condition but in same table mysql

Tags: mysql, database

can i make having count on my query syntax in multiple condition?
its my query

```
SELECT * FROM absen WHERE keterangan = 'Sakit' HAVING COUNT('keterangan') >= 1 
AND WHERE keterangan = 'Alpa' HAVING COUNT('keterangan') > 5
```

but in single condition is work perferctly
Thanks for helped

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Yup you can have multiple condition but doesn't need to write where clause every time just use AND to apply both conditions

Comment: not same where condition but different * check my edited post

Comment: `SELECT * FROM absen WHERE keterangan = 'Sakit' HAVING COUNT('keterangan') >= 1 AND COUNT('keterangan') > 5` this would give u the result which have count as per both conditions

Comment: and 'keterangan' equals to 'sakit' and 'alpa' not only 'sakit', please check my edited post i make some mistake :)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM absen WHERE keterangan = 'Sakit' OR keterangan = 'Alpa' HAVING COUNT('keterangan') >= 1 AND COUNT('keterangan') > 5`

Answer (score 0):

You are using WHERE condition two time , this will produce empty rows
You can extend WHERE conditions by using AND operator

This would be right query >

SELECT * FROM absen WHERE keterangan = 'Sakit' HAVING COUNT(keterangan) >= 1

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot write multiple where clauses and multiple having clauses in the same query